# XML bounding boxes to shapefile QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, xml

I used [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) to create some bounding boxes around items of interest on a TIF image. I am wondering if I can convert those XML bounding boxes into shapefiles? I've looked at a few other posts for converting `xml` to `shp` or even `csv` to `shp`, but those posts are all dealing with lat/lon coordinates. Unfortunately, I have `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, `ymax` values that seem to be specifically attached to the image/tif that I drew them on.

So I am confused on how I could convert to a shapefile when the `xml` does not have any georeference information. I could add the georeference information because my image/tif contains it, but I am still not working with lat/lon coordinates. Perhaps I could convert the mins/maxs into lat/lon?

Any suggestions on how I might approach this problem?

[image]

**Edits**:

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061428/convert-labelimg-xml-rectangles-to-labelme-json-polygons-with-image-data) that someone has posted. I however am using a `.tif` for an image and they are using a `.jpg`. I am unaware if that will screw up the `encoded` parameter? The code is running, but I do get the printed error: `error in labelme conversion: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'. The "data_test.json" is saved, but only contains` {}`.

**Edits 2:**

[image]

Comment: what is the unit in bnbbox?

Comment: Are xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rasterio` for getting geo-coordinates from pixel coordinates, and `pyshp` (`shapefile`) for creating a shapefile.

```py
import rasterio
import shapefile # -> pyshp module
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# get pixel coordinates from XML
root = ET.parse('/path/to/file.xml').getroot()
xmin = float(root.findall('object/bndbox/xmin')[0].text)
ymin = float(root.findall('object/bndbox/ymin')[0].text)
xmax = float(root.findall('object/bndbox/xmax')[0].text)
ymax = float(root.findall('object/bndbox/ymax')[0].text)

tif_file = '/path/to/tif_file.tif' # georeferenced TIFF
shp_path = '/path/to/shapefile' # don't add extension

# open georeferenced tif file
with rasterio.open(tif_file) as image:
    ## get vertices of the bounding box
    # geocoordinates from pixel coordinates
    p1 = image.xy(xmin, ymin)
    p2 = image.xy(xmax, ymin) 
    p3 = image.xy(xmax, ymax) 
    p4 = image.xy(xmin, ymax) 

    # save shapefile containing one bounding box shape
    w = shapefile.Writer(shp_path + '.shp')
    w.field("name", "C") # pyshp needs at least one field
    w.poly([[p1, p2, p3, p4]]) # generate bbox polygon
    w.record('bbox')
    w.close()
    
    # generate .PRJ file
    crs_wkt = image.crs.to_wkt()
    prj = open(shp_path + '.prj', "w")
    prj.write(crs_wkt)
    prj.close()
```

[image]

Comment: I am continuing to run into an error: `NoneType object has no attribute 'to_wkt'`. Also, does this code work for multiple bounding boxes within an xml file?

Comment: Are you sure the tif file is georeferenced? If `image.crs`  returns nothing or None, the tif file is not georeferenced.

Comment: `image.crs` returns nothing. I apologize, I thought it was georeferenced.

Comment: I assumed the tif was georeferenced because when I opened it up in Label Img with the corresponding xml, the bounding box would show. So somehow they are tied together.

Comment: I've attached a picture of the information I have in my tif

Comment: Sahbaz, Sorry it's been a while. I was finally able to get your code to work. If you have more than one bounding box (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) in the `.xml` file, it will not work. I'll troubleshoot this problem now.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, use the code below, install rasterio, geopandas and shapely modules before running this code.

**Code to do the task**.

```
import os
import shapely
import rasterio
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


#Once the environment and libraries are installed, 
#ensure all the XML files are in the directory.
#In this cell, we use the listdir to get all files in the directory, 
#and using the if condition, select only the .xml files
all_input_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".xml")]


#An empty list is created to append all dataframes (each XML file will create one dataframe). This list is used to concatenate all the dataframes into a single dataframe.
conc = []

'''
Step1: In the first for loop we are iterating over all .xml file in the directory .getroot() will return the root element for a particular tree (xml file).
Step2: Access the XML tree (ET=Element Tree), get the root of the tree structure, then from the root get the particular filename of XML.
Step3: Now replace the .png with .tif extension tag, so we can read the same GeoTIFF file and get the spatial data.
Step4: Let us find all bounding boxes and iterate over them to get the CRS for each box. This is a loop inside another loop. Inside the loop, we get the name for each bounding box and bounding box extent.
Step5: Extracting the max and min values of the X and Y-axis. X and Y are different in image space and coordinate space. xmin in the image is Ymin in the coordinate space.
Step6: Getting the point data from X and Y coordinates.
Step7: Create a polygon from the point data generated.
Step8: Creating metadata from shapefiles, after this, the inner loop end, Step 4 to 8 are iterated, all bounding box extents are calculated, and polygon geometry is formed.
Step9: Now, a pandas DataFrame is created, and the data frame is added to the conc list.
'''

# Step 1 # Loop Start
for input_file in all_input_files:
    
    #Step 2
    tree = ET.parse(input_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    file_name = root.find('filename').text
    
    #Step 3
    geotiff_name = file_name.replace('png', 'tif')
    data = []
    
    #Step4 Loop start
    for el in root.findall('object'):
        name = el.find('name').text
        bndbox = el.find('bndbox')
        
        #Step5
        Ymin = int(bndbox.find('xmin').text)
        Ymax = int(bndbox.find('xmax').text)
        Xmin = int(bndbox.find('ymin').text)
        Xmax = int(bndbox.find('ymax').text)
        
        #Step6
        with rasterio.open(geotiff_name) as image:
            crs = image.crs
            p1 = image.xy(Xmin, Ymin)
            p2 = image.xy(Xmax, Ymin) 
            p3 = image.xy(Xmax, Ymax) 
            p4 = image.xy(Xmin, Ymax)
          
        #Step 7 
        poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon([[p[0], p[1]] for p in [p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]])
        
        #Step 8
        datadict = {}
        datadict['name'] = name
        datadict['geometry'] = poly
        datadict['image_name'] = file_name
        data.append(datadict)
        # Inner loop End
    
    #Step 9
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    conc.append(df)
# Loop End


#By using the pandas concatenate, we are merging all the dataframes into a single dataframe.
df = pd.concat(conc)

#Let's use the pandas dataframe, and add the geometry and the CRS to make it a spatial layer.
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs=crs)

#Now the GeoDataFrame is exported as Shapefile.
output_file = 'output.shp'
gdf.to_file(output_file)
print("ShapeFile is successfully created.")
```